# How can I include a reason for a transaction, if the transaction is created by observing a field of user?

Tags: php, laravel

My users table has a field of points, and I have an Observer that tracks specifically that field. When that field is updated, a new record of TransactionPoints is created by triggering an event.

My Observer:

```
class UserPointObserver
{
    /**
     * Handle the User "saved" event.
     * 
     * @param \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function saved(User $user)
    {
        if ($user->isDirty('points')) {
            event(UserPointsChanged::class);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know how can I include the reason it was created. (reason is also a field of TransactionPoints)

For example, if the User gained points by completing an achievement, I want the string "achievement" to be able to reach the Listener (since Observer triggers the event and the event triggers the listener).

I thought of moving the reason from the TransactionPoints table to the Users table, but I think that would be counter-intuitive and lead to problems later on.

Comment: From a database point of view, it may make more sense to maintain a table with the points and the reason for the points.  The User would then use this table to determine the current points they have.  Sound like you are doing this the other way round and trying to work out the changes from the User change.

Comment: @NigelRen How would I track multiple reasons in that case? For example one user who gained points through achievements, purchase, interactions.

Comment: If your TransactionPoints table has a user id, a reason and the points - your code should be adding to this table directly.  This would also allow you to change the points if some error was made, or allow you to work out what has changed and when.  If you just have 1 score in the user table, it can get out of line at times and difficult to re-calculate.

Comment: @NigelRen So can I reverse the structure and instead use an Observer to sum the points of the user in the Transaction table and pass it to the users table? Sorry if I'm insisting in having a field with the total, it's really important. Thanks for your help

Comment: You could do, so as another record is added - you can adjust the total on the User.

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel 5.3+**

Not tested, but might help.

- create a constructor in your observer that can get request

---

```
protected $request;

public function __construct(Request $request)
{
    $this->request = $request;
}
```

---

- Then in your observer, you can pass the data to event and then to listner

---

```
event(new UserPointsChanged($this->request->reason));
```

---

- Get data in UserPointsChanged Event

  public $reason;

  ```
   public function __construct($reason)
   {
       $this->transaction = $reason;
   }
  ```
- Then use in handle method.